# Persistence Object Naming Convention

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, poco

I have some POCOs and there are corresponding persistence objects that do the CRUD. What is a good name for the persistence objects? I've seen people use the term "service objects" for these, but when I think service, I think WCF. Maybe "persistence objects" is the best, but I'd like to hear what other people think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common convention is the Repository pattern when dealing with persisting objects to a datastore, so you would expect to see naming conventions in the form of (given an corresponding type Poco):

```
PocoRepository
```

Comment: I actually am using the repository pattern with NHIbernate and Ninject, so repository would probably be the best answer in my specific case here.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for the "Data Access Object", or DAO suffix.

Say you have the concept of a customer in your code, and a customer table in your database, then you may end up with the following model:

- **CustomerDAO** - A class that maps directly to the customer table. This is your "Persistence class". Maybe it has some technical fields such as database index id or sequence
- **Customer** - A class that represents your business logic. Maybe this lacks some of your database related fields, but has some additional business related fields or methods. For instance when you store a birthdate it may have a calculateAge() method.
- **CustomerDTO** - A class that represents what your API exposes to the outside world. This means it may not expose birthdate due to privacy reasons. But instead it may expose additional fields such as "coupons" because it may be useful for the caller to obtain these as well. As Kevin Swiber already referenced above and linked to Martin Fowler

Often you'll see these 3 functions being performed by one and the same class, but this is not considered best practice. Unless you are building a very simple application, splitting them up is better. Whether this is worth the effort and does not overengineer/overcomplicate things is a design decision you have to make.

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are thinking of a [*Data Transfer Object*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object).

Answer (score 2):

Data Transfer Objects, or DTO's, is a common way to refer to these objects.

See Martin Fowler's definition: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just adding "persistor" to the name, like Person_persistor etc, if the persistence objects just are used for persisting.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following conventions:

- `<YourName>`: The domain class you want to persist. (e.g. `User`)
- `<YourName(pluralized)>Repository`: The class which persist/store your domain class. (e.g. `UsersRepository`)
- `Persitent<YourName>` *(optional)*: The class which is really persisted/stored. (Your repository should take your domain class and map it to this persistent model before saving it.) (Could be located in a `PersistentModels` folder.)

Answer (score -1):

I believe "Entities" is a commonly used and traditional name.

Comment: Entities have nothing to do with persistence. He clearly stated that he has separate objects that do persistence.

Comment: epitka is right; Entities will typically be the objects that are to be persisted.